# triple DES in nodejs compared to through openssl

Tags: node.js, encryption

*fist of `xxd -p` in the following example adds "0a" in the end of the hex. No idea why, this is why you notice that I use the first parameter `$1` in the openssl encryption, I have generated the hex manually and inserted it as so..*

---

```
#!/bin/bash
KEY=`echo $1 |xxd -p`;
openssl enc -e -des-ede -nosalt -K $1 -iv "0000000000000000" -in $2 -out $3;
```

called as so:
`sh encrypt.sh 583645585458304c4f39524756514456 settings.conf settings.enc`

---

in node.js however I use the following encryption:

```
const key = Buffer.from('X6EXTX0LO9RGVQDV');

module.exports = (file, callback) =>
{
  const
  iv      = new Buffer(0),
  cipher  = require('crypto').createCipheriv('des-ede', key, iv);

  callback(null, cipher.update(file, 'utf8', 'binary'));
}
```

...and trigger this as so:

```
require('fs').readFile(__dirname + '/settings.enc', (error, enc) =>
  require('fs').readFile(__dirname + '/settings.conf', (error, conf) =>
    require('./file-encrypt')(conf, (error, enc2) =>
    {
      enc2 = Buffer.from(enc2, 'binary');
      console.log('compare: ', Buffer.compare(enc, enc2));
    })));
```

But output is never "0" (meaning, they are never the same - tested with: `console.log('compare: ', Buffer.compare(enc2, enc2))` that ofc logs a beautiful `0`)

**Why are these not equal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a call to `cipher.final()` to get any remaining bytes after you are done providing all plaintext data. Try this instead:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const key = Buffer.from('X6EXTX0LO9RGVQDV');

module.exports = (file, callback) =>
{
  const iv = Buffer.alloc(0);
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede', key, iv);
  callback(null, Buffer.concat([
    cipher.update(file),
    cipher.final()
  ]);
}
```

and use like:

```
require('fs').readFile(__dirname + '/settings.enc', (error, enc) =>
  require('fs').readFile(__dirname + '/settings.conf', (error, conf) =>
    require('./file-encrypt')(conf, (error, enc2) =>
    {
      console.log('compare: ', Buffer.compare(enc, enc2));
    })));
```

Also, you can omit the `-iv "0000000000000000"` from the `openssl` command line since the IV is not used by `des-ede` and avoids a warning printed to the console.

Comment: also removed the iv from nodejs: `createCipheriv` => `createCipher`

Comment: You shouldn't change that since `createCipher()` *generates* (using MD5) a key based on the password argument you pass to it. Since you already have the exact key, you should use `createCipheriv()` as you were originally.